# How to get the number of partitions in CosmosDB MongoDB API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

In order to tune the performance of a CosmosDB for MongoDB API, I need to get the number of partitions in a collection.

The naive way of doing this would be to query for all distinct values for the partition key, like this (in C#):

```cs
var results = await SomeCollection.Distinct<string>("PartitionKey", filter: "{}").ToListAsync();
```

But of course this would need to look at every single document or at least scan the whole index and fails with `Query exceeded the maximum allowed memory usage of 40 MB. Please consider adding more filters to reduce the query response size...`.

I have also looked at the [PartitionKeyRangeStatistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.documentcollection.partitionkeyrangestatistics?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_DocumentCollection_PartitionKeyRangeStatistics) but that explicitly states `If your partition keys are below 1GB of storage, they may not show up in the reported statistics`,
which applies to most of the partitions.

Any ideas on how to get an accurate count of the partitions in a collection?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Get [`Partition Key Ranges`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/get-partition-key-ranges) API in CosmosdbYou can retrieve the list of partition key ranges (physical partitions)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I need the number of *logical* partitions, not physical ones.